# I want to fetch Product Names on behalf of comma separated SKU's

Tags: magento2, database, sql

I want to fetch Product Names on behalf of comma separated SKU's i.e. sku1,sku2,sku3 and the expected result is Name1,Name2,Name3

Comment: where you want to fetch ? i.e phtml, block

Comment: I have a custom table where product SKU's are saved in column

Comment: I have a custom table in which a column have Comma Separated ProductSku's in want to fetch Product Names of Behalf of these SKU's

Comment: OK, so did you able to get those SKUs ? and need to show where ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$skuList = 'sku1, sku2, sku3, sku4';
$exlodeList = explode(',', $skuList);
$productNamesArray = [];
for($exlodeList as $sku) {
  $productObj = $productRepository->get(trim($sku));
  $productNamesArray[] = $productObj->getName();
}
print_r($productNamesArray); // array output
$productNamesString = implode(",", $productNamesArray); // for comma separated names output
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your SKUs as an array like below.

Loop the SKUs

```
$values[] = array("finset"=>array($sku));
```

Then use the below filter

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('sku',$values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used FIND_IN_SET function to find particular Id and the Group_Contact to Merge it Again

$collection = $this->_connectordetailsFactory->create()->getCollection();
$this->setCollection($collection);

```
    $collection->getSelect()
    ->columns('CONCAT((SELECT nametable.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS nametable LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity ON nametable.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id WHERE  nametable.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM   eav_attribute WHERE  entity_type_id = 4 AND attribute_code LIKE "name" AND catalog_product_entity.sku = main_table.connector_sku ))) AS connector_name');


    $collection->getSelect()
    ->columns('CONCAT((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(" ", phone_data.phone_make, " - ",phone_data.phone_model ," ") FROM phone_data WHERE FIND_IN_SET(phone_data.phone_id,main_table.phone_id))) AS phone_name');

    
    $collection->getSelect()
    ->columns('CONCAT((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(" " , nametable.value , " ") FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS nametable LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity ON nametable.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id WHERE  nametable.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM   eav_attribute WHERE  entity_type_id = 4 AND attribute_code LIKE "name" AND FIND_IN_SET(catalog_product_entity.sku,main_table.product_sku) ))) AS product_name');
```